# Toggle show list of buffers in vim

Tags: vim

There is this cool tip in Vim wikia to work with buffers:

```
nnoremap <F5> :buffers<CR>:buffer<Space>
```

How can I turn it into a toggle? That is, first press of `<F5>` shows the list of buffers, press it again, and it closes the list of buffers (for me it's more intuitive than pressing ESC) Also, I would like to do the same for `:Hex` with, say `<F2>`, that is, press `<F2>`, opens file explorer in a split, repress `<F2>`, closes file explorer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'turn it into a toggle'.

Comment: I use `Alt-t` with this mapping: `map <M-t> :tab sball<CR>` Press Alt-t and each buffer opens in its own tab, making switching to them easy.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what you mean by toggling buffer list. You can dismiss the command line via `<esc>`. I guess you could do `cnoremap <f5> <esc>`. This works because pressing `<f5>` in normal mode brings up the buffer list and keeps you in command-line mode. You map `<f5>` in command-line mode to `<esc>` to dismiss the prompt.

`:Hex` opens a split an netrw explorer buffer. You can simply close the buffer any number of ways: `<c-w>c`, `:q`, `:close`, and so on. To make an `<f2>` mapping that closes a netrw buffer you can add the following to you `~/.vimrc` file:

```
augroup ToggleNetrw
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType netrw nnoremap <buffer> <f2> :<c-u>close<cr>
augroup END
```

Your `<f2>` mapping does `:Hex` and we map a buffer specific `<f2>` mapping for netrw filetypes to close the buffer via `:close`.

Comment: While `cnoremap <f5> <esc>` works, I was expecting a more elegant solution. Sorry I didn't clarified, I edited the question now.

Answer (score 0):

`:Lexplore` will toggle the explorer in the current buffer's directory.

You can map  to something like:

```
nnoremap <F2> :Lex<CR>
```

alternatively you can give a size for the opening netrw:

```
nnoremap <F2> :20Lex<CR>
```

In the above example, `20` is the percentage drawn from the current buffer size.
More information can be found by the vim command: `:h Lexplore` among other resources.

------- EDIT about toggling buffer list.

You can toggle the buffer list after executing the mapping you have by pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key, if that's what you mean.